# Java Utility to know if Kafka broker is up/down in 9.0?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Is there any way to check directly if Kafka broker is up or down in version 9.0 using java code.

Though i can check if Zookeeper is up using below code:

```
ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient("11.22.33.44:2181", 1000, 1000, kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
```

if **zkClient** object *is not null OR no exception* it means its connected.

Older versions had below code to fetch brokers list:

**`Seq<Broker> allBrokersInCluster = ZkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster(zkClient);`**

But how to check in version 9.0 of kafka & latest version of ZkClient/Zookeeper APIs using java code?

Though i tried below way to get the count/broker list.

```
zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.BrokerIdsPath());
zkClient.countChildren(ZkUtils.BrokerIdsPath());
```

But above codes cannot identify if Broker is shutting down or getting ready to start (STATES).

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code on Kafka 9.0 and working for me:

```
Seq<Broker> allBrokersInCluster = ZkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster(zkClient);
JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(allBrokersInCluster).forEach(b->{
            System.out.println("Broker: "+b.connectionString());
        });
```

It will print connection strings of all active brokers.

Comment: you must be using old zookeeper/zkclient libs ? i have 'zkclient-0.9' & 'zookeeper-3.4.8'

Comment: BTW i can get broker list & count using 'zkClient.countChildren(ZkUtils.BrokerIdsPath())' & zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.BrokerIdsPath())